# SVG cannot resize to parent container

Tags: svg, embed

Hi guys i have a problem in IE 11. I  have a embed svg which need to interact with its elements... Here is the example just click on floor 5 :

http://infinityproperty.sitetester.biz/floorplans/59

In Chrome and Firefox everything is ok bur in IE it is too little? What could make this thing?

Comment: I tried it, and it worked fine for me in IE11. It looked the same as Chrome.

Comment: I just managed to make it and will post the answer. It was a css hack.

Answer (score 0):

For someone which try everything to resize svg in ie there is a problem with inline svg. When you try to resize it in 100% width it works fine in the major browsers but IE refuse to resize it.
I have managed it to work with one css hack here it is.

Conteiner:

```
#svg {
display: inline-block;
padding-bottom: 70%;
position: relative;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 100%;
}


#svg svg {
display: block;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

Also remove the width and height of the svg.

With this i got it to work. :)